# Non-existence of a homeomorphism between two sub-spaces of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Let $A_n = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{n}\}$ , $n\geq 1$ and let $B = \{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:-1\leq x\leq 1\}$. Prove that:
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{3}A_n\cup B \mbox{ is not homeomorphic to } \bigcup_{n=1}^{5}A_n\cup B.
$$
I tried to suppose the existence of such a homeomorphism and restricted the domain by removing the intersection points between $B$ and the $A_n$ , then I also restricted the codomain by removing the images of the points I've eliminated from the domain. Then this map should also be a homeomorphism, but the number of connected components of the restricted domain is different from the connected components of the restricted codomain. The problem is that it's kind of obvious that the number of connected components is different, but how to prove it? Is there a quicker method to prove the non-existence of such a function? Thank you in advance for every hints or advices (or even better the solution to this problem).

Comment: If $X^k=\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n\cup B$ and $I^k=\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n\cap B$ then $I^k=\{(\pm\frac{1}{n},0)\ |\ n=1,\ldots,k\}$ is the set of your "intersection" points. It has exactly $2k$ elements. Note that you don't have to count components of the complement, it is enough to count intersection points. Easier, faster and equivalent. However you need to show that every homeomorphism $X^k\to X^s$ maps $I^k$ onto $I^s$. This is what is hard here, not counting. I would approach this by noticing that $x\in I^k$ if and only if $x$ has no neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A far more simple proof can be given through homotopy, can you use it?

Comment: Interesting approach @freakish !! In the general topology course I have followed I have never seen this proposition.. I could try to figure out how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @simo210 not really.. my professor talk about it but we're not allowed to use it for this problem, unfortunately.